# QGIS 3 processing script is recognized as a model

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-3

I refer to the QGIS 3 (QGIS 3.4.4-1, 64Bit standalone installer) processing script shown below. If I copy the script, do *Create New Script...* from the processing toolbox, paste it to the empty script and save it as, let's say `xlsx_vector_writer.py` the script is somehow added to *scripts*, but as a *model* like this:

[image]

Note the Algorithm:ID **'script:model'** which to me is a contradiction in itself, and should be **'giswg:xlsxvectorwriter'**, as stated in the source code below.

When I right-click it, it behaves like a *script AND a model as well*:

[image]

one may verify, that this is the script just saved by selecting 'Edit script...'.

Q: Is anyone able to reproduce this? What might it be that causes this weird behavior?

This is the script:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import *
import processing, datetime

class XLSXVectorWriterProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    MIDFIX = 'MIDFIX'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return XLSXVectorWriterProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'xlsxvectorwriter'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('XLSX Vector Writer')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('giswg')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'giswg'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Export Vector as XLSX with filename as projectfolder_midfix_date.xlsx")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                self.MIDFIX,
                self.tr('The middle of this fine output filename (fix)')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        input_vec = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )

        midfix = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.MIDFIX,
            context
        )

        feedback.setProgressText('get project folder')
        projectfolder = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance()).variable('project_folder')
        prefix = projectfolder.split('\\')[-1].lower()
        feedback.setProgressText('get date')
        today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

        feedback.setProgressText('make filename')
        filename = '{0}_{1}_{2}.xlsx'.format(prefix, midfix, today)

        feedback.setProgressText('write xlsx')
        crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem() #instead of None
        w = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(input_vec, '{0}/{1}'.format(projectfolder, filename), 'utf-8', crs, 'XLSX')

        return {}
```